# Cognos Two Datetime Prompts Seconds Difference

Tags: datetime, db2, prompt, cognos

I would like to calculate seconds difference between two datetime prompt values. I would like to do it by using query calculation. I'm using DB2 and i have to use DB2 functions. I have somthing like this but it didn't work for datetime prompts, it works only like this:

```
(DAYS(localtimestamp) - DAYS([FIRSTOCCURRENCE])) * 86400 + 
(MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(localtimestamp) - MIDNIGHT_SECONDS([FIRSTOCCURRENCE]))
```

I want to use it like this :

```
(DAYS(?endDate?) - DAYS(?beginDate?)) * 86400 + 
(MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(?endDate?) - MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(?beginDate?))
```

How can i do that ? Is there anyway to do this ?

PS: localtimestamp gives **Aug 20, 2014 5:26:51 PM** kind of result. But prompt gives **2014-08-21T10:53:09.166**. Thats the main problem i couldn't convert it.

Comment: You're saying `localTimestamp` - does your "locality" have DST (at which point days aren't always 24 hours)?

Comment: thats just a example. localtimestamp gives 'Aug 20, 2014 5:26:51 PM' kind of result. But prompt gives '2014-08-21T10:53:09.166'. Thats the main problem i couldn't convert it.

Comment: ...What's the type of `localTimestamp`?  `CHAR` or `VARCHAR`?  You may have to call (or even write) one of the parsing functions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query calculation should be like this, i finally figured it out:

```
(hour(substring (?endTime?,1,8))*3600+minute(substring (?endTime?,1,8))*60+second(substring (?endTime?,1,8)))-
(hour(substring (?beginTime?,1,8))*3600+minute(substring (?beginTime?,1,8))*60+second(substring (?beginTime?,1,8)))+_days_between (?endDate?,?beginDate?)*86400
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
_days_between(?endDate?;?beginDate?) * 86400 +
(extract(hour; #prompt('endDate', 'timestamp')#) - extract (hour; #prompt('beginDate', 'timestamp')#)) * 3600 +
(extract(minute; #prompt('endDate', 'timestamp')#) - extract (minute; #prompt('beginDate', 'timestamp')#)) * 60 +
 extract(second; #prompt('endDate', 'timestamp')#) - extract (second; #prompt('beginDate', 'timestamp')#)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is Cogos Common Function `CAST`. It is processed by Cognos itself. You can convert days to seconds:

```
Cast (_days_between(?endDate?;?beginDate?), INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND)
```

It would be great if you can update your answer and mark where you need to use data items (in `[]`), parameters (in `??`), Cognos functions and separately DB2 functions.

Comment: Unfortunately you are wrong
1. INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND
2. Function _days_between returns integer value (Cognos BI 10.2)

Comment: @AlexeyBaturin. 1. Not wrong, but a typo - updated. 2. Am I saying something else?

Comment: 2. You can't get seconds from integer days.